# Where are gcloud configurations stored on disk?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I just switched computers and lost all my custom `gcloud config configurations`. I have files backed up from the old machine, but can't figure out which one has the configurations setup. How can I re-enable the old configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, looks like they are stored in `~/.config/gcloud/configurations/` and you can just copy them over to use them.

```
$ ls .config/gcloud/configurations/
config_dev  config_prod  config_staging
```

Comment: Why not copy entire .config/gcloud? Note that configuration has references to accounts and keys, and if these are not copied you will have to recreate them.